# Result on direct product of groups

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G=A \times B$ is finite group as a direct product of $A$ and $B$ and let $U \leq G$. If $N \leq U$ for all $N\unlhd A$ then $A\subseteq U$.

I start by letting $a\in A$ be arbitrary. If $a\in N$ then $a\in U$ and we are done. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Are you identifying $A$ with the subgroup $A \times 1$ of $G$? If so, then we can just choose $N = A$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your reasoning for choosing $N =A$?